# Finding the inverse of an element in $\Bbb Q[a]$

Tags: abstract-algebra

I'm really in trouble to find the inverse of that element =) please help me!

$a$ is a complex root of the polynomial $x^4 + x^3 +1$.
So what's the inverse of $a^2 + a + 1$ in the ring $\Bbb Q[a]$?

Answer (score 3):

**Hint**

The application of the extended Euclidean algorithm to $f = a^2 + a + 1$ and $g = a^4 + a^3 + 1$ in $\mathbb Q[a]$ yields polynomials $s,t\in\mathbb Q[a]$ with
$$fs + gt = 1.$$
Do you see how to get the inverse of $a^2 + a + 1$ from this representation?

Comment: Well, it shows that the inverse of f is exist. It's also better for me to know this than answer of the question. Thanks for hint. Let me get the inverse.